# Why isn't the background image showing up?

Tags: java, jpanel, jpeg

I'm writing a program for a Hangman game and I want the background to be a JPEG image, rather than just a solid color. But when I run my program, the background image isn't showing up. Any thoughts?

HangmanFigure.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class HangmanFigure extends JPanel {
       private int guesses;
       private Image background;

          public HangmanFigure() {
             super();
             guesses = 0;
             setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

             //setting background color
             //setBackground(Color.BLACK);

             //setting background image to JPEG
             background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("/Desktop/scaryTown.jpg");

             //set to true because we want to see the background
             setOpaque(true);
          }

          @Override
          public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
             super.paintComponent(g);

             g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
             //No need to worry about the rest of the elements in this method, I'm just having issues with the background image!
             ...
          }
       }
```

In another file, called MainWindow.java, I have the main method. (That's where I provide the graphics for everything else that's not part of the Hangman figure). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the image file in the directory that the program is being run from?
If it is not in the same directory you need to navigate TO that directory...

use ../<Complete file path>

Comment: Oh! It isn't, so if I moved that image into the directory, it should work? Then can I just say "scaryTown.jpeg" instead of what I have up there? And thanks!

Comment: Yeah exactly! The application looks in the root directory for any files to be included.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally works! :)

Comment: Woohoo! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try to add the resource folder which contains your background photo to the build path by right click the folder in eclipse then build-path --> use as source folder , and you juste have to put "/YoursourceFolderName/scaryTown.jpg"

if you are using command line to compile use the following command :

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath YourSourceFolder pathToTheJavaCode/*.java
```

Comment: You do realise, by including the "YoursourceFolderName" the image will become an embedded resource, meaning that when the op tries executing the jar file outside of the IDE, it is likely that the image won't load (as they are referencing the File and not the resource)